# Что такое "норма" в русском языке

Tags: терминология

По результам обсуждения вопроса о предлоге "про".

Вопросы.
~1. Т.н. разговорный стиль - что это? Категория лингвистическая или стилистическая?
~2. Я вляется ли разноворная норма подмножеством (разновидностью, частью) нормы общелитературной? Если да, то что вообще такое "норма"?

Я лично исхожу из понятия "нормы", явно или неявно прослеживающейся в орфоэпических, например словарях: нормативно-разгноворно-просторечно-неправильно-грубо_неправильно.
Отдельно стоят характеристики "несвободно" и "книжное". Они напрямую не связвны с нормативностью.

С небольшими вариациями эта шкала реализуется везде. Поэтому разговоры о том, что разговорый стиль - разновидность нормы для меня не очень понятны с точки зрения лингвистики.

Да вот еще что. Как вы оцениваете следующее высказывание:

> Для разговорной речи характерен разговорный стиль, но эти термины не совпадают: понятие “разговорная речь” шире, чем понятие “разговорный стиль”, так как в разговорной речи реализуется не только разговорный стиль литературного языка, но и другие функциональные стили (ср., например, устная научная речь), и нелитературные элементы.

http://advokated.ru/2012-09-09-18-16-23/514-stil_formy_i_zhanry_rechi.html
Это не самый авторитетный источник, но подобные высказывания попадались мне и раньше.
Не в этом ли смешении разговорной речи и разговорного стиля и кроется причина непонимания?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Думаю, норма понятие относительное. Норма - это то, что нормально для какого-то контекста. Книжная норма "не нормальна" для разговорного текста. Мат же в определенных кругах является нормой, ведь это тоже часть языка.

Мы привыкли к понятию литературной нормы как к высшей форме языка. Может, потому и возник хороший вопрос по поводу разговорного стиля и лексики (да, надо стилистику и лексикологию разграничить, согласна с Виктором): являются ли они нормой? Очевидно, да, иначе зачем фиксировать разговорную лексику в словарях. То есть это норма для разговорного стиля. И да, я согласна, что это разновидность литературной (вот термин "общелитературная норма" мне как-то не по душе, можно запутаться, что для чего является общим) нормы, ее ответвление, что ли.

Я бы поставила "книжный уровень" все-таки в одну шкалу: 
книжно (очень, слишком правильно) - нормативно (правильно) - разговорно (не очень правильно) - просторечно (неправильно) - грубо (очень неправильно). Только не знаю несвободно: это как?..

Разговорный стиль - категория стилистики, которая граничит с литературоведением и жанрами.
Разговорная лексика - лингвистическая категория, точнее категория лексикологии как раздела лингвистики. И когда лексика соответствует стилю - тогда это будет называться нормой, по-моему. Но проблема в том, что стилей в чистом виде "в природе" почти не бывает. Поэтому и понятие нормы колеблется.

Я бы опасалась употреблять в данном случае термин "разговорная речь" (ведь имеется ввиду лексика вроде). Речь, как я уже раньше говорила, - явление реальное (даже конкретное, и хаотичное), а язык - понятие абстрактное (систематизированное). (Так нас учил мой любимый преподаватель в универе.) Короче, речь - практика, язык - теория.

В общем, я так это все понимаю.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, что главная причина, приведшая к сформулированной Вами проблеме,- это то, что Вы, как мне показалось, не разводите два разных понятия - "разговорная лексика" как термин из области лексикографии и "разговорный стильречи" как сфера стилистики. Насколько мне помнится, в той дискуссии о "про" в комментариях коллега делала замечание по поводу того, что Вы исключили разговорные слова из литературного языка, коими они являются. Вы же в ответе своем писали о разговорном стиле.